# Count all joined table rows when filtering by the same joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm querying a table districts, that has one to many relationship with the positions table.
I want to select the districts that have the positions with particular name AND count ALL districts positions at the same time. Can I do this?

With the current code

```
 SELECT districts.*, COUNT(DISTINCT(positions.id)) as positions_count FROM "districts"
  LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.id = districts.position_id
 WHERE ("positions"."name" IN ($1, $2)) GROUP BY districts.id ORDER BY positions_count desc, "districts"."name" ASC
```

If I have 20 positions in some district but only 2 are filtered, positions_count eq 2 as well, I want it to be 20

I've tried to join twice on the same table with an alias but this gives me the same result

```
SELECT districts.*, COUNT(DISTINCT(positions_to_count.id)) as positions_count FROM "districts"
  LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.id = districts.position_id
  LEFT JOIN positions AS positions_to_count ON positions_to_count.id = districts.position_id WHERE ("positions"."name" IN ($1, $2)) GROUP BY districts.id ORDER BY positions_count desc, "districts"."name" ASC
```

Comment: Are you using Postgres or MySQL?  They are quite different databases.

Comment: Something's amiss here. It sounds like districts have positions and you want to show districts that have certain positions. Your query mostly looks like this, too. But the tables are linked by a position ID and not by a district ID, i.e. it's not that districts have positions, but positions have districts. And thus the whole request doesn't make any sense for me. Can you please clarify? Maybe sample data and expected result would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the filtered positions to get the districts that you want in the results and then join all the positions:

```
SELECT d.*, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) as positions_count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT d.* 
  FROM districts AS d INNER JOIN positions AS p 
  ON p.id = d.position_id
  WHERE p.name IN ($1, $2)
) AS d INNER JOIN positions AS p
ON p.id = d.position_id
GROUP BY d.id 
ORDER BY positions_count DESC, d.name ASC
```

I'm not sure about `DISTINCT p.id`. You can also try without `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT d.*, COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) as positions_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.name IN ($1, $2) THEN p.id END) as positions_name
FROM "districts" d LEFT JOIN
     positions p 
     ON p.id = d.position_id 
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY positions_count desc, d."name" ASC;
```

Note:  If you do not have duplicates for a given district, then there is no need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, just `COUNT()` suffices.

Comment: This way I'm getting all districts, but I want to get the districts that have the positions with the particular names